# как написать программу на python которая будет работать в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, windows

можно ли написать программу на python, которая после запуска не будет показываться, то есть будет работать как в фоновом режиме? прямо как Rat вирус, если да то как? Есть ли статьи про это?

Comment: Есть разница между запуском `python.exe` и `pythonw.exe`, второй по-моему не создает консольных окон

Answer (score 3):

К запускаемому файлу укажите расширение `*.pyw` - консоль открытв не будет.

Comment: спасибо, а как его потом остановить?

Comment: через диспечер задач или реализуйте управление через сеть (web, telegram, telnet, значок в трей) telnet самое простое